# How to fix "This relative module was not found " in Laravel + Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Sorry for every one I am newbie in laravel with vue to build Single Page Application . I did a lot of trials in my case, but still not working at all

1. I really wanted to import the vue component inside another vue component , this means is 'Nesting Components' .
2. But when i save why npm run watch working, gives me an error about "This relative module was not found "

**This will Import** from   "resource/js/component"  component named as **Hello.vue**

```
<template>
<h1> hello </h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name:'Hello'
}
</script>
```

**This will get an import Hello.vue**

```
<template>
<h1> world</h1>
</template>

<script>

import Hello from './js/component/Hello

export default {
  name:'Hello'
}
</script>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Are you trying to import the **hello** component into the **hello** component??

Comment: Yes sir , I really wanted to import that component but I've got error

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking about here is [Recursive Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Recursive-Components).

When using recursive components you don't need to import them as they are the component you want to use. You simply need to make sure it has a `name` and the element inside your component template matches that name (case-insensitive

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>hello</h1>

        <hello></hello>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Hello'
    }
</script>
```

The above code will actually cause an error because it's essentially creating an infinite loop so you would need to have some condition(s) in your component to prevent this e.g.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1> hello </h1>

        <hello v-if="showNested" show-nested="false"></hello>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {

        props: {
            showNested: {
                default() {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        },

        name: 'Hello'
    }
</script>
```

Obviously, I would imagine that you know why you want to nest the components so you can write the logic accordingly.

---

As for the error you're getting, I would imagine this is because of the path you've supplied to for your import.

When using `require` or `import` the `.` refers to the current directory so assuming that the path for the `Hello` component is:

```
resources/js/component/Hello.vue
```

you've essentially tried to import:

```
resources/js/component/js/component/Hello
```

This is very much a non-issue now but I thought I would point it out.